# Kivy is not detecting touch inputs in my application

Tags: kivy, multi-touch, raspberry-pi2

I am using Kivy on Raspberry Pi, utilizing the new official 7" touchscreen.  I am trying to make an application that utilizes the touch screen for simple button/accordion operations but the input does not reach the kivy program.  Am I missing something important from the below code?

The touchscreen works fine in X, and I can also cat /dev/input/event0 and see data on the buffer when making multitouch gestures.

According to Kivy itself, I'm definitely initializing the touchscreen when starting the app:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-09-16_22.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1-dev
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 177 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <FT5406 memory based driver>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range ABS X position is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range ABS Y position is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <FT5406 memory based driver> range position Y is 0 - 480
```

My source code is very elementary:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App

def button_pressed():
    exit(0)


class CarInterfaceApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CarInterfaceApp().run()
```

and my kv file is likewise pretty simple:

```
#:kivy 1.0

Accordion:
    min_space: 60
    orientation: 'vertical'
    AccordionItem:
        title: 'Car'
    AccordionItem:
        title: 'Music'
    AccordionItem:
        title: 'Messaging'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the default config file for kivy, config.ini, has `provider=hidinput` in the [input] section.  If you change this to `provider=mtdev`, the FT5406 works fine!

Answer (score 4):

I had 2 issues to solve to get this working on Arch Linux Arm.

The first issue was the one that Peter's answer covers - I didn't have mtdev in my config. I set the `[input]` section of my `~/.kivy/config.ini` to

```
[input]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

The 2nd issue was that the stderr had

```
[INFO              ] [ProbeSysfs  ] unable to found provider mtdev
[INFO              ] [ProbeSysfs  ] fallback on hidinput
```

The solution here was to install mtdev with `pacman -S mtdev`

Comment: I had a similar issue. The original TFT was unresponsive to finger press but was working with a mouse click. The issue was a comment in the same line as 
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev # problematic comment. The correct way is to have the comments in separate lines.